# Associated has_one and belongs_to models using "where"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, models

I want users to be able to close projects rather than destroy them. And I want to store the close reasons in a separate table to the project itself. I am trying to do this through associated models.

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project_status
  has_one :project_close_reason, -> { where 'project_status_id = 10'}
end

class ProjectCloseReason < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :projects
end

class ProjectStatus < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :project
end
```

I only want the ProjectCloseReason when a user cancels a project (Which entails changing the project_status_id in the Project to '10'). However, when I create a new project now, it keeps giving me an error that the project close reason must exist. Any thoughts how this can be achieved? The above `{ where... }` doesn't seem to work in this situation?

**UPDATE**

Clarifying my associations, the `project_status` model has a predefined list of statuses:

(Eg: 1: Pending, 2: Analysing, 3: Working, ..., 10: Cancelled).

The foreign_key is sitting in the Project model so that each project would have one project_status_id -> This foreign_key column is what I'm referring to in the `{ where... }` option in the Projects model associations.

Comment: Do you have any default project status value set for a project? I guess setting a default value to 0 would solve the issue

Comment: Thanks I have added a default value, but it's still returning the same error

Comment: project.project_status_id is always 0? When you create a project?

Comment: I have added a default value now that each new product has a default `project_status_id` of '1'. Originally I had sort of done this by manually setting the value in the Project#create Action to '1' (which achieved the same thing I believe). It worked, but realise now that wasn't a good way to handle it so thats fixed now thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rethink about the associations among the models. You can try this:

**project.rb**

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :project_status
  has_one :project_close_reason, through: :project_status
end
```

**project_status.rb**

```
class ProjectStatus < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  has_one :project_close_reason, -> { where status: 10 } #assume 'status' is an attribute where you store you project status such as 10
end
```

**project_close_reason.rb**

```
class ProjectCloseReason < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project_status
end
```

Comment: `where 'project_status_id = 10'` will return an AR collection, which does not look like has_one ;)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko yes correct :) , need to reverse that association. Foreign key should be added to the model where `belongs_to` association is mentioned i.e `ProjectStatus` model.

Comment: Thanks, I realise I actually had another issue in the model when you pointed this out! I've added an update and edited the question to show the revised associations - the change to the belongs_to to has_one hasn't affected the error I'm getting :/ Any other thoughts?

Comment: Ah I didn't see your revision, thank you. Currently the `ProjectStatus` stores predefined list of statuses. And the `ProjectCloseReason` has a `Comment` field to capture why the person is closing the project, and is also storing the `last_project_status` to keep track of when it was cancelled. I chose this file structure so that I can eventually edit the `ProjectCloseReasons` to have a foreign_key linking to another list of predefined closed reasons. It felt the most robust way of doing it?

Comment: Ah fixed! I had a typo and still had a duplicate instance of the belongs_to still sitting in the method. Fixed! Thanks :):) Your original solution worked!